# Facebook Open Graph: Friends RSVP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to use Facebook Open graph to get a list of a users friends that have RSVPed to an event using the new v2.2 facebook open graph

I can get a list of all the RSVPs - it lists ALL of them

I can get pass each RSVP to see if they are a friend of the user, but that requires A LOT of calls to open graph.

Whats the easiest way to do this?

Comment: There is no direct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, there is no direct way in Facebook open graph to get the list of friends of the user who have RSVP'd to an event. You can use the user/friends edge to get the list of friends (who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request) and try to match these lists together without making a lot of extra calls. This document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends covers what the users/friends edge returns.